# get user after LockedOut time has passed AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm logging my login
I've logged the first time user tries to sign in and fails
and when user gets locked out
but now I need on how to log when users lockedout time has passed and can try to sign in again
something like : the user {UserName} has been unlocked and can try to sign in again

```
   var result = await _SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememeberMe, true);
                                if (result.Succeeded)
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                                        return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //messages with title == null are used in relationship (chat) page
                                        unreadReceivedMessages = _MessageRepository.GetReceivedMessages(producer.UserId).Where(m => m.Title != null && !m.IsRead).AsQueryable();
                                        unreadSentMessages = _MessageRepository.GetSentMessages(producer.UserId, null).Where(m => m.Title != null && !m.IsRead).AsQueryable();
                                        Response.Cookies.Append("noOfUnreadReceivedMessages", unreadReceivedMessages.Count().ToString());
                                        Response.Cookies.Append("noOfUnreadSentMessages", unreadSentMessages.Count().ToString());

                                        string protectedUserId = _protector.Protect(producer.UserId);
                                        AlarmViewModel alrm = new AlarmViewModel();
                                        alrm.Link = protectedUserId;
                                        Response.Cookies.Append("UidUs", protectedUserId);
                                        #region UserLog
                                        UserLog userLog = new UserLog
                                        {
                                            UserId = producer.UserId,
                                            Ip = remoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                                            LoginDateTime = DateTime.Now
                                        };
                                        _AccountRepository.AddUserLog(userLog);
                                        #endregion
                                        return RedirectToAction("Alarm", "Notification"/*, new { userId = protectedUserId }*/, alrm);

                                    }
                                }
```

when it gets locked

```
                                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                                {

                                    _Logger.LogInformation($"The User {currentUserID} Has been LockedOut with Ip: {Ip}");

                                    return View("AccountLocked");
                                }
```

The first time user fails

```
                    _Logger.LogInformation($"The User {currentUserID} Had a Failed Login attempt  with Ip: {Ip}");
```

Actually I want to know how can i set smth like trigger in sql server in the aspnet core backend that if smthing changed smthing happens?

Comment: I don't bother because I feel it unnecessary to go to this extent. A user is either locked out until x or they are not. They attempt to log in (the event that drives all this) and you either end up telling them "you are locked out until date X/for another Y seconds, try again after that" or they log in successfully. If you really want you can put some JS on the page that will count down a "you are locked out for another 10.. 9.. 8.." but is there any point? Even if your message is static "try again in 27 seconds" and they try after 10 they get "try again in 17 seconds".. dynamic enough?

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually I want to know how can i set smth like trigger in sql server in the aspnet core backend that if smthing changed smthing happens?

Comment: @CaiusJard i need this to happen to get my security certificate in here

Comment: What something happens?

Comment: Question is making less sense.. Triggers in sqlserver only respond to external events, not some timer timeout